# Error in syntax passing multiple variables using redirect

Tags: php, get

I have a form that collects data from a user and inserts them into a mySQL database.  My problem is to present the data submitted to the user using redirect.  I created a simple function, `redirect_to($var1)` that works OK.

Problem arises with this syntax:

```
redirect_to("serraRedirect1.php?lastname=$_GET['lastname']&firstname=$_GET['firstname']&emailconf=$_GET['emailconf']&entree=$_GET['entree']&lastname2=$_GET['lastname2']&firstname2=$_GET['firstname2']&entree2=$_GET['entree2']&meal_cost=$_GET['meal_cost']");
```

The error message is `'unexpected "' in line xxx`.

I've made several changes but nothing I did works.

I need help in getting the syntax right.

Comment: Put `" . ` before each `$_GET`; and put ` . "` after each `']`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to concatenate..

Do like this

```
redirect_to("serraRedirect1.php?lastname=".$_GET['lastname']."&firstname=".$_GET['firstname']."&emailconf=".$_GET['emailconf']."&entree=".$_GET['entree']."&lastname2=".$_GET['lastname2']."&firstname2=".$_GET['firstname2']."&entree2=".$_GET['entree2']."&meal_cost=".$_GET['meal_cost']);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are including a value from an array in a double-quoted string, you need to surround it in curly brackets (`{` and `}`):

```
redirect_to("serraRedirect1.php?lastname={$_GET['lastname']}&firstname={$_GET['firstname']}&emailconf={$_GET['emailconf']}&entree={$_GET['entree']}&lastname2={$_GET['lastname2']}&firstname2={$_GET['firstname2']}&entree2={$_GET['entree2']}&meal_cost={$_GET['meal_cost']}");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect_to("serraRedirect1.php?lastname={$_GET['lastname']}&firstname={$_GET['firstname']}&emailconf={$_GET['emailconf']}&entree={$_GET['entree']}&lastname2={$_GET['lastname2']}&firstname2={$_GET['firstname2']}&entree2={$_GET['entree2']}&meal_cost={$_GET['meal_cost']}");
```

Comment: The second curly bracket is messed up: `{$_GET['lastname']{` => `{$_GET['lastname']}`

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect_to( sprintf("serraRedirect1.php?lastname=%s&firstname=%s&emailconf=%s&entree=%s&lastname2=%s&firstname2=%s&entree2=%s&meal_cost=%s",
    $_GET['lastname'], $_GET['firstname'], $_GET['emailconf'], $_GET['entree'], $_GET['lastname2'], $_GET['firstname2'], $_GET['entree2'], $_GET['entree2']
));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the *get* method, everyone could see all the inforamation for all the users in your database.
In these situations I prefer to use sessions:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
redirect_to(.....);
```

and:

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

in serraRedirect1.php